# PDO and MySQL 'between'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to get PDO to work with a MySQL 'between'. Below is my code:

```
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);  

$start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, 11, 1, 2009));
$end_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(23, 59, 59, 11, 30, 2009));

$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `start_date` BETWEEN ':start_date' AND ':end_date'");
$STH->bindParam(':start_date', $start_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH->bindParam(':end_date', $end_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH->execute();
var_dump($row);
```

What gets returned is an array with '0' or 'NULL' for values. When I hard code the end date, it acts as if `start_date` is set to -1, retuning me all rows before the `end_date`. So, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't wrap the values with single quote.

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `start_date` BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date");
```

Comment: Both were correct, but I'll mark this one as the answer for your speed, haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Do not put quotes around params:

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `start_date` BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date");
```