# PHP PDO usage with MySQL BETWEEN and INET_ATON()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I started a PHP side project a while back, and recently started cleaning up all the code and updating it. Part of that is moving things to start using PDO for DB queries.  In one particular query I have a `WHERE` clause statement that uses the `BETWEEN` clause along with the `INET_ATON()` function. So far I have not been able to get this to work properly and would appreciate if anyone can point out whether or not it will even work.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514357/pdo-and-mysql-between) question which leads me to believe that the `BETWEEN` statement is not having any issues, but I fear it might be the combination with the function causing the issue.

Here is what that portion of my query looks like:

```sql
SELECT foo, bar FROM table JOIN more_table 
WHERE item1 = :value AND ip_address BETWEEN INET_ATON(:ipstart) AND INET_ATON(:ipend)
```

The actual query is quite a bit larger than that, but for basics this works. To replace the tokens with the actual values I have the following foreach loop set up (the `var_dump` is just there so i can verify the correct values are getting passed in, which they are):

```
foreach($p as $k=>$v) {
    echo var_dump($k, $v);
    if(is_int($v)){
        $querySubmit->bindValue($k, $v, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    } else {
        $querySubmit->bindValue($k, $v, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
}
```

If anyone knows whether `PDO::Prepare` and `PDO::bindValue` have any limitations with a query set up to use `BETWEEN` and `INET_ATON()`, I would greatly appreciate knowing!

Comment: pdo has absolutely **NO** knowledge of mysql functions. as long as the mysql parser doesn't reject the query string, PDO will happilly shove in whatever you want, wherever you want it.

Comment: I'm not sure what is causing this to fail then.  I can get it to run perfectly fine if I run the query for a single IP address (ie: AND ip_address = INET_ATON(:ip); ). It's only when I use the BETWEEN clause with the function that it does not return any results.

Comment: so... what is the error message?

Comment: what are you sending as an IP? remember that inet_ntoa/aton only do IPv4.

Comment: After some time away from the keyboard, and a day of debugging, I finally fixed this. It was actually an issue with a different section of the code and not the part passing values to the SQL query.  Thanks all for the responses!

@MarcB I was passing IPv4, no IPv6 (yet) so that will be a beast to tackle another time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being with a separate section of code.  The values being passed into the SQL query were correct, and the `bindValue` operation was working successfully.

To anyone who reviews this question in the future, who believes they are having a similar problem, if set up correctly there should be no issues with using the `INET_ATON/NTOA()` functions with `BETWEEN`.

I believe the first comment, left by @MarcB, was probably the best answer to this actually, "PDO has absolutely NO knowledge of MySQL functions. as long as the MySQL parser doesn't reject the query string, PDO will happily shove in whatever you want, wherever you want it."

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter for `bindValue()` is `$k`  it should be `:value`

```
foreach($p as $k=>$v) {
    echo var_dump($k, $v);
    if(is_int($v)){
        $querySubmit->bindValue(:value, $v, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    } else {
        $querySubmit->bindValue(:value, $v, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
}
```

Also are you binding `:ipstart` and `:ipend`?

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer, however I resolved this issue and it ended up being a separate section of code, and not the passing of values to the SQL query and binding them.

Also, the value stored as `$k` was the equivalent of `:value`.